# How to change site title on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the site title's h1(.site-h1) to another text when down scrolling with jquery. For example, "my site" changes "welcome" when scrolling.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```html
<nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-container">
        <div class="site-h1">
          <h1>my title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-bar">
          <div class="menu-title">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MENU</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contactme">
          <button type="button" name="button">CONTACTME</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #F4F7F6;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar .site-h1 h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
  color: #202221;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.navbar .menu-title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .menu-title h2 {
  margin-top: -65px ;
  padding: .7rem 1.2rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transition: 1s;
}

.navbar .menu-title h2:hover {
  color: #A6ABAB;
}

.navbar .contactme {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.navbar .contactme button {
  background-color: #DF3E7B;
  color: #F4F7F6;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: .7rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .contactme button:hover {
  background-color: #dd85a5;
}
```

Comment: Where is you javascript?

Comment: @GetSet Just this part needs js and i didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: You mean of all the internet, there is nothing on scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By when scrolling, I assume that you mean on all the document. For this we use jQuery [scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) method.
But you can notice that in order to optimize it, I'm using jQuery [One](https://api.jquery.com/one/) here to  prevent the script from firing the event many times at every tiny scroll change.

```js
$(window).one('scroll', function() {
    $('.site-h1 h1').text('Welcome! Happy Scrolling :)');
    console.log('scroll detected!');
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #F4F7F6;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar .site-h1 h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
  color: #202221;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.navbar .menu-title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .menu-title h2 {
  margin-top: -65px ;
  padding: .7rem 1.2rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transition: 1s;
}

.navbar .menu-title h2:hover {
  color: #A6ABAB;
}

.navbar .contactme {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.navbar .contactme button {
  background-color: #DF3E7B;
  color: #F4F7F6;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: .7rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .contactme button:hover {
  background-color: #dd85a5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-L/W5Wfqfa0sdBNIKN9cG6QA5F2qx4qICmU2VgLruv9Y=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-container">
        <div class="site-h1">
          <h1>my title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-bar">
          <div class="menu-title">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MENU</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contactme">
          <button type="button" name="button">CONTACTME</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="somespace">
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
     Some Text
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(window).one('scroll', function() {
    $('.title').text('Welcome');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="title">Hello welcome </h1>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```